# Pandas dataframe: how to multiply a specific value by using its row index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I want to change specific values in a Pandas dataframe.  Here is an example dataframe (in reality, there are many more rows):

```
              Value                       Property
0               CH4                       Type
1          -10.90979                      Density (g/cm3)
2           5.00000                       Temperature (K)
```

Here I want to multiply "`10.90979`" by `10` in the row labeled "`1`".  I don't want to have to write "`10.90979 * 10`" because I only know that I have a property called "`Density (g/cm3)`".  I don't know its value.  So I want to use the index of the row in which "`Density (g/cm3)`" appears in the multiplication.

I have tried:

```
row_index = df.index.get_loc(df[df['Property'] == 'Density (g/cm3)'].index[0])
new_value = df.iloc[row_index][0] * 10
df["Value"].replace(df.iloc[row_index][0], new_value, inplace=True)
```

However, this gives me weird output.  I get:

```
              Value                       Property
0               CH4                       Type
1 -10.90979-10.90979...                   Density (g/cm3)
2           5.00000                       Temperature (K)
```

I can't post the details of the code but am hoping someone will recognize a simple mistake.  I am not sure that I'm using multiplication correctly for a dataframe.  I also tried using

```
df.iloc[row_index][0].mul(10)
```

but get the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mul'`.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like the `Value` column is a string, not a number. So `*` repeats the string instead of multiplying the number.

Comment: you need to convert `Value` to a number if you want to multiply it arithmetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others pointed out, your `Value` column is not numerical (because of the `'CH4'` first value). But, more fundamentally, why do you want to multiply the density by `10`? What's the higher level problem?

From this question (and your previous one, now deleted), it looks like you have chemical compounds and are trying to do unit conversions on their physical properties. I would recommend looking into packages that do that readily. For example: [`pint`](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and its pandas companion [`pint_pandas`](https://pint-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

It seems that you have DataFrames with a chemical compound (e.g., `'SO2'` or `'CH4'`) as the value of the first row, and then some physical properties.

You may be better off using dicts to represent your properties. E.g.:

```py
from pint import UnitRegistry

Q_ = UnitRegistry().Quantity

compounds = {
    'CH4': dict(
        name='methane',
        molar_mass=Q_(16.043, 'g / mol'),
        density_0=Q_(0.657, 'kg/m**3'),
        at_0=Q_(25, '°C'),
        density_1=Q_(0.717, 'kg/m**3'),
        at_1=Q_(0, '°C'),
        density_2=Q_(422.8, 'g/L'),
        at_2=Q_(-162, '°C'),
    ),
    'SO2': dict(
        name='sulfur dioxide',
        molar_mass=Q_(64.066, 'g / mol'),
        density_0=Q_(2.6288, 'kg / m**3'),
        at_0=Q_(25, '°C'),
    ),
}
```

Then, if you like, you can convert this into a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pint_pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(compounds).T
```

and convert a specific column into some desired unit, for example:

```py
>>> df['density_0'].astype('pint[g/L]')
CH4    0.6570000000000001
SO2    2.6288000000000005
Name: density_0, dtype: pint[gram / liter]

# or (shudder):
>>> df['density_0'].astype('pint[lb/gal]')
CH4     0.0054829307249767
SO2    0.02193839922346841
Name: density_0, dtype: pint[pound / gallon]
```

or convert the whole DataFrame to have consistent units for each column:

```py
z = df.astype(dict(
    molar_mass='pint[g/mol]',
    density_0='pint[g/L]',
    density_1='pint[g/L]',
    density_2='pint[g/L]',
    at_0='pint[degC]',
    at_1='pint[degC]',
    at_2='pint[degC]',
))

>>> z
               name  molar_mass           density_0  at_0           density_1  at_1  density_2  at_2
CH4         methane      16.043  0.6570000000000001    25  0.7170000000000001     0      422.8  -162
SO2  sulfur dioxide      64.066  2.6288000000000005    25                 nan   nan        nan   nan

>>> z.dtypes
name                        object
molar_mass       pint[gram / mole]
density_0       pint[gram / liter]
at_0          pint[degree_Celsius]
density_1       pint[gram / liter]
at_1          pint[degree_Celsius]
density_2       pint[gram / liter]
at_2          pint[degree_Celsius]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I hadn't seen the previous questions. This does look like a better approach given the type of data.

Comment: @Pierre D thank you so much for this advice.  I am just waking up and didn't see your response until I had accepted the earlier one.  Both answers are very helpful.  Yes, right now I am dealing with chemical data and your advice about pint is very helpful indeed. I'll take a look.  Some of my units are pretty crazy so I'll be interested to find out whether pint is useful! I'll consider your comment about using dicts. The reason I'm using dataframes is I'm finding it easier for importing data from external files. Yes, I deleted my previous question because I realized it wasn't well-formulated.

Comment: @Ant if you think this is a better solution, you should accept it (I really don't mind) as it will be easier for future users to find the best solution that way.

Comment: @Nick, that's very generous.  Thank you.  I need to think hard about Pierre's suggested approach but get the sense that it would be more elegant than what I'm currently doing.  I'd like to improve my style.  As I said, your answers are both very helpful but maybe it would be particularly useful for future readers to know about pint and to be alerted to the usefulness of dicts for dealing with properties.

Comment: @Ant no worries at all. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that because of the `CH4` value in the `Value` column, values in that column are treated as strings when you try to multiply them; thus

```
'-10.90979'*10 = '-10.90979-10.90979-10.90979...'
```

You need to convert the value to float to operate on it. Note you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing) to access all the `Density` values:

```
mask = df['Property'] == 'Density (g/cm3)'
df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df.loc[mask, 'Value'].astype(float) * 10
```

Output:

```
      Value         Property
0       CH4             Type
1 -109.0979  Density (g/cm3)
2   5.00000  Temperature (K)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `where` dataframe function for replace value:

```
df['value'].where(df['property']!='Density (g/cm3)', df['value']*10, inplace=True)
```

But, the `where` function only replace values when the condition is `false`:

```
!='Density (g/cm3)'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

use `where` & `filllna`

```
cond = df['Property'].eq('Density (g/cm3)')
df.assign(Value=df['Value'].where(cond).astype('float').mul(10).fillna(df['Value']))
```

out:

```
      Value         Property
0       CH4             Type
1 -109.0979  Density (g/cm3)
2   5.00000  Temperature (K)
```

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Value': ['CH4', '-10.90979', '5.00000'], 
         'Property': ['Type', 'Density (g/cm3)', 'Temperature (K)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: thank you.  This didn't work for me.  When I'm free tomorrow, I will figure out why.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ant Do you know that Pandas functions do not overwrite the original? then there is no reason why my code should not work. My code itself is the product, not change df.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is at my end.  I will work on it.  Thank you.